# In selenium can we retrieve text from a webpage when the text doesn't exist in HTML but coming from api response?

Tags: java, html, api, selenium-webdriver, textfield

So there is some text in text field and the HTML doesn't show the text
[Text field with HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLD4y.png)

Is it possible for selenium to pick the text "test" if the text is coming from an api

Comment: Its not the same it is different then waiting for ajax call to complete

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomExpectedConditions {
    public static ExpectedCondition pageStateToBeReady() {
        return object -> (((JavascriptExecutor) getDriver()).executeScript("return document.readyState")).equals("complete");
    }
}

public static void pageToBeLoaded() {
        try {
            new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), TIMEOUT).until(CustomExpectedConditions.pageStateToBeReady());
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            log.info(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
            throw new TimeOutError("Page is not loaded");
        }
    }
```

Use this code snippet. It will wait for page load. After it, data from API will be available.

Comment: the data never appear after complition of call or anything